# numpy/pandas NaN difference confusion

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I happened onto this when trying to find the means/sums of non-nan elements in rows of a `pandas` dataframe. It seems that

```
df.apply(np.mean, axis=1)
```

works fine.

However, applying `np.mean` to a `numpy` array containing nans returns a nan.

Is this all speced out somewhere? I would not want to get burned down the road...

Comment: Save yourself with `np.nanmean`.

Comment: @Divakar does the same work with `np.sum`, `np.std` and the rest?

Comment: @Divakar I see the answer is yes, but the question still stands: why does the semantics in `pandas` and `numpy` differ (given that the function used in `pandas` is `np.mean`).

Comment: I would think the function used in pandas would be nanmean, but we need to verify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

numpy's mean function first checks whether its input has a mean method, as @EdChum explains in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43865763/2285236).

When you use `df.apply`, the input passed to the function is a pandas.Series. Since pandas.Series has a mean method, numpy uses that instead of using its own function. And by default, pandas.Series.mean ignores NaN.

You can access the underlying numpy array by the values attribute and pass that to the function:

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.mean(x.values), axis=1)
```

this will use numpy's version.

Answer (score 1):

Divakar has correctly suggested using np.nanmean

If I may answer the question still standing, the semantics differ because [Numpy supports masked arrays,](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) while [Pandas does not.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#nan-integer-na-values-and-na-type-promotions)