# np.cumsum(df['column']) treatment of nans

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

`np.cumsum([1, 2, 3, np.nan, 4, 5, 6])` will return `nan` for every value after the first `np.nan`. Moreover, it will do the same for any generator. However, `np.cumsum(df['column'])` will not. What does `np.cumsum(...)` do, such that dataframes are treated specially?

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'column': [1, 2, 3, np.nan, 4, 5, 6]})

In [3]: np.cumsum(df['column'])
Out[3]: 
0     1.0
1     3.0
2     6.0
3     NaN
4    10.0
5    15.0
6    21.0
Name: column, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `np.cumsum(object)` with an object that is not a numpy array, it will try calling `object.cumsum()` See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865602/how-do-numpy-functions-operate-on-pandas-objects-internally) for details
. You can also see it in the [Numpy source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/0d13f9f747887b290108a909dd92c3cb47239921/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L51).

The [pandas method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) has a default of `skipna=True`. So `np.cumsum(df)` gets turned into the equivalent of `df.cumsum(axis=None, skipna=True, *args, **kwargs)`, which, of course skips the NaN values. The Numpy method does not have a `skipna` option.

You can also verify this yourself by overriding the pandas method with your own:

```
class DF(pd.DataFrame):
    def cumsum(self, axis=None, skipna=True, *args, **kwargs):
        print('calling pandas cumsum')
        return super().cumsum(axis=None, skipna=True, *args, **kwargs)

df = DF({'column': [1, 2, 3, np.nan, 4, 5, 6]})

# does calling the numpy function call your pandas method?   
np.cumsum(df)
```

This will print

```
calling pandas cumsum
```

and return the expected result:

```
    column
0   1.0
1   3.0
2   6.0
3   NaN
4   10.0
5   15.0
6   21.0
```

You can then experiment with the result of changing `skipna=True`.